# mb_send_mail() sends 2 same mails on chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, email

My php mail form sends 2 same mails each time.

I'm new to php. I've tried things I can do, but couldn't find the solution by myself so far...

- PHP version is 5.2.17
- It somehow works right on IE, Firefox and Safari on Windows 8.
- Use mail() instead of mb_send_mail(), but it was the same.
- The contents of the mails I received from the form seems OK.
- Uploaded on another server, but was the same.
- Simple code without any other code, with very simple HTML also didn't work properly.

  example: mb_send_mail( "[email address]", "Test", "It's a test mail", "From:[email address]" );

Here's my code from the form.

**form.html**

```
<form action="./confirm.php" method="post">
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

*Uses Angular to validate.

**confirm.php**

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if(!$_POST){
        header('Location: ./form.html');
    }
   foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        ${$key} = $value;
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
?>
<form action="./send.php" method="post">
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

**send.php**

```
session_start();

$email_address = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
$message = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$message .= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

mb_language("ja");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$header = "From:".$email_address."\n";
$header .= "Reply-to:".$email_address."\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer:PHP/". phpversion();

mb_send_mail($_SESSION['email'],"subjecct",$message,"From:$email_address");

session_destroy();
```

Why is my code sending each mail twice, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What happens after the mail is sent on both IE and Chrome? Do you see a blank page? Does it redirect somewhere else?

Comment: In confirm.php you don't have any `session_start();` before you use the global variable `$_SESSION`?

Comment: @mrunion I did't set redirect or any other action after sending. Send.php just shows text like "have sent".

Comment: @zairwolf So sorry! It's my mistake. I added session_start() but forgot to paste here...

Answer (score 0):

After `session_destroy();`, add some debug marks to check if this PHP runs twice.
e.g. `file_put_contents('debug.txt', file_get_contents('debug.txt')+1);`

It can help.

Comment: Thanks zairwolf. I tried it and which says "2"! So probably it runs twice. But few sec later. So it because of html? I'll check my coding once again. Thanks a lot, at least could find what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @zairwolf for your advice to add a debug line.
Now it's working correctly.

Not sure which made solve it because I've tried few things to fix it.
I think it could be one of these:

- Added session token which is like:

  **confirm.php**

  ```
  $token = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
  ```

  **send.php**

  ```
  $key = array_search($_POST['token'], $_SESSION['token']);
  if ($_SESSION['xxxxx']=="" || $key == false) {
    header('Location: ./error.php');
  }
  ```
- Separate "thankyou.php" from "send.php"

  I put both "sending program" and "showing thank you html" in "send.php" actually. So noticed might should separate it somehow.